# Find SQL function from SQL statement in C# using regex

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex

I want to parse a SQL statement which may use a SQL function inside the query text. Now using C# regex I'd like to parse the string and check if there is any function name(s) used inside the query and extract those. There may be multiple functions used inside the query and each function can have `n` number of parameters which is not known from before hand.

```
select * from fnTest(@A, @B) 
select x.* from fnTest(@A, @B) x join fnHelloWord(@C, @D, @E) y on x.SomeID = y.OtherID
```

- In the first sample the regex would return a string value `fnTest`.
- In the second sample the regex would return a list of function name strings like `fnTest` and `fnHelloWord`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your string are like those you showed, then you can use a regex like this:

```
\w+(?=\()
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hM9lX5/1)**

[image]

Btw, if you want to grab the regex content use capturing groups like:

```
(\w+)(?=\()
```

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [14-20] `fnTest`
MATCH 2
1.  [46-52] `fnTest`
MATCH 3
1.  [68-79] `fnHelloWord`
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Fede's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25269876/801579), You may also need to allow for some number of whitespaces between the function name and the open parenthesis.

e.g. `\w+\s*(?=\()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://regex101.com/r/iO3wO0/1) regex:

```
@"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\([^\)]*\)"
```

Basically `([a-zA-Z0-9]*)` matches an identifier (a-z, A-Z, or 0-9) and captures it, `\(` matches a left parenthesis, `[^\)]*` matches any number of things which are not right parentheses, and then finally `\)` matches a right parenthesis.

Alternatively, you could use [this](http://regex101.com/r/rS7dH9/1) regex:

```
@"(\w*)\([^\)]*\)"
```

Becaue `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.